# Windows Phone Back Button VB

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1

I have been trying to get the back button to work for windows phone using vb, however I cant find anything on the internet, anything I do find is for c#

Can someone please tell me how I can make the back button go to the previous page as every time the back button is pressed it quits out of the app.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at VB so, I'll make it in C# and consider to do it in your way in VB

In the Constructor of a page, write this code :

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

In the Page's class, write this :

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            this.Frame.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Consider to write it in all pages.

Comment: If you do this on each page, don't forget to unsubscribe from the BackPressed event when navigating away from the page - otherwise the event handler will keep the page alive and the event will be handled multiple times. If the event handler is the same on each page, you could have just one global BackPressed handler in the app class.

Comment: I tried it once to make the BackPressed event handler in app.cs but it didn't work perfectly.